# Entity Framework 4 - List<T> Order By based on T's children's property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity, sql-order-by, generic-list

I have the following code -

```
 public void LoadAllContacts()
        {
            var db = new ContextDB();
            var contacts = db.LocalContacts.ToList();
            grdItems.DataSource = contacts.OrderBy(x => x.Areas.OrderBy(y => y.Name));
            grdItems.DataBind();
        }
```

I'm trying to sort the list of the contacts according to the area name that is contained within each contact. When I tried the above, I get "At least one object must implement IComparable.". Is there an easy way instead of writing a custom IComparer?

Thanks!

Comment: So Areas is another list of entities, i.e. each LocalContact has more than one Area? How do you want the ordering to work with multiple child elements - can you give an example? It may well come down to extracting some information from Areas, e.g. the string name of the first Area, and ordering on that.

Comment: That's correct - Areas is another list of entities. I want this list to be sorted by name. Contact 'XYZ' could be part of 'Asia' and 'Africa'. Contact 'ABC' could be part of, say, just 'New Zealand'. I want to see XYZ at the top of the grid, followed by ABC. Make sense?

Comment: Not really. What if XYZ is part of Africa and New Zealand and ABC is part of France? Then does XYZ come first because Africa < France even though New Zealand > France? Or do you need to repeat XYZ in the list, i.e. XYZ for Africa, ABC for France, XYZ for New Zealand? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
public void LoadAllContacts()
{
    var db = new ContextDB();
    var contacts = db.LocalContacts.ToList();
    grdItems.DataSource = contacts.OrderBy(x => x.Areas.OrderBy(y => y.Name).First().Name);
    grdItems.DataBind();
}
```

this will order the contacts by the first area name, after ordering the areas by name.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: fixed error in code. (.First().**Name**)

Comment: Bad idea. What if you have millions of contacts? This will fetch them ALL in memory.

Comment: Bad idea for the solution, or for the method in question? the method is "supposed to" load ALL contacts! if it's the solution that's bad, then I tried the query and seen the generated SQL (using LinqPad) and the ordering is done at the database level, not in memory (meaning that the Areas aren't loaded to memory)

Comment: @AbdouMoumen I am very sorry, I didn't read the question properly. My bad. It's just that I'm allergic to seeing `ToList` calls without `Where` or `Take` :-)

Comment: Your statement that the ordering is done in the database doesn't make much sense to me however... Unless you mean that the Areas are lazy loaded in which case you have a SELECT N+1 problem...

Comment: @jeroenh I've put an example here http://tinypaste.com/3e2931 that's the way I see it, maybe you can correct me :)

Comment: @AbdouMoumen could not summarize everything in a comment, see my own answer.

Comment: one small additional note: if there is a Contact with no Areas, you will get a InvalidOperationException...

Answer (score 2):

I was in a discussion with @AbdouMoumen but in the end I thought I'd provide my own answer :-)

His answer works, but there two performance issues in this code (both in the answer as in the original question).

First, the code loads ALL contacts in the db. This may or may not be a problem, but in general I would recommend NOT to do this. Many modern controls support paging/filtering out of the box, so you'd be better off supplying an not-yet-evaluated `IQueryable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. If however you need everything in memory, you should delay the `ToList` to the last possible moment.

Second, in AbdouMoumen's answer, there is a so-called 'SELECT N+1' problem. Entity Framework will by default use lazy loading to fetch additional properties. I.e. the Areas property will not be fetched from the database until it's accessed. In this case this will happen in the controls '`for` loop', while it's ordering the result set by name.

Open up SQL Server Profiler to see what I mean: you will see a SELECT statement for all the contacts, and an additional SELECT statement for each contact that fetches the Areas for that contact.

A much better solution would be the following:

```
public void LoadAllContacts()
{
    using (var db = new ContextDB())
    {

        // note: no ToList() yet, just defining the query 
        var contactsQuery = db.LocalContacts
            .OrderBy(x => x.Areas
                       .OrderBy(y => y.Name)
                       .First().Name);  

        // fetch all the contacts, correctly ordered in the DB
        grdItems.DataSource = contactsQuery.ToList();

        grdItems.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, so it's just the "ToList" that was in the original code and which I didn't notice before ;)
I think you have to add `.First().Name` after the inner `OrderBy`, that expression should return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Is it one to one relation `(Contact->Area)`?
if yeah then try the following :

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Area != null)
               return this.Area.Name;
            return string.Empty;
        }
     }
 }
```

then

```
grdItems.DataSource = contacts.OrderBy(x => x.AreaName);
```

Comment: Can you do that in EF4? Doesn't it moving this into a separate property count as an Invoke which can't be computed by the SQL expression engine? (or am I thinking of EF 3.5?)